# cannot retrieve data into variables from dynamic sql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to get a table name dynamically (cursor 1), and then trying to retrieve data from this table (table 1) into variables and then trying to insert these variables into into another table (table 2) along with the table name and other data retrieved in original cursor 1. But what I find is that the data inserted in table 2 only contains the data retrieved from the cursor 1. But other fields that are supposed to be fetched from table 1 are null. This means the variables are empty. I have also generated a debug sql which works nicely when I remove the variables.

I am a newbie at writing procedural SQL. Could anyone please help me. And this I believe may serve as an example, because I didnt find any good example in net on this kind of problem.

This is the debug statement output. It returned result when I ran it separately without the variable. The original code snippet is given after it.

```
SELECT COUNT(week_of_year),  AVG(naivemape) avgnaive, SUM(original+naive2mape), AVG(f1mape) , AVG(f2mape), AVG(f3mape),AVG(f4mape), AVG(f5mape),STDDEV(f1mape), STDDEV(f2mape), STDDEV(f3mape),STDDEV(f4mape), STDDEV(f5mape) INTO 
                vcountweek,
                vavgnaive,
                vtotal_sale,
                vavgf1mape,
                vavgf2mape,
                vavgf3mape,
                vavgf4mape,
                vavgf5mape,
                vstddevf1mape,
                vstddevf2mape,
                vstddevf3mape,
                vstddevf4mape,
                vstddevf5mape

FROM zdata2_7_Canberra_Mel_2014allout_day_1 WHERE stepserial IN (4)

    DELIMITER $$

    USE `x_data`$$

   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `create_zdata2_thesis_2014_summary`$$

   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `create_zdata2_thesis_2014_summary`( )
   BEGIN

    DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;

    DECLARE vtable_name VARCHAR(500);
    DECLARE vweekday    VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE vboarding_station_name VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE vdeboarding_station_name VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR SELECT output_table, RIGHT(output_table,1), boarding_station_name, deboarding_station_name FROM `x_data`.`z_thesis_logtable`;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET no_more_rows = TRUE;


    OPEN c1;
    LOOP1: LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO vtable_name, vweekday, vboarding_station_name,vdeboarding_station_name ;
        IF no_more_rows THEN
        CLOSE c1;
        LEAVE LOOP1;
        END IF;

        BLOCK1STEP: BEGIN

            DECLARE vcreatestmt VARCHAR(5000);
            DECLARE vweekday INT(4);
            DECLARE vcountweek INT(4);
            DECLARE vstepserial INT(4);


            DECLARE vtotal_sale DECIMAL(41,8);
            DECLARE vavgnaive DECIMAL(22,12);   
            DECLARE vavgf1mape DECIMAL(22,12);
            DECLARE vavgf2mape DECIMAL(22,12);
            DECLARE vavgf3mape DECIMAL(22,12);
            DECLARE vavgf4mape DECIMAL(22,12);
            DECLARE vavgf5mape DECIMAL(22,12);
            DECLARE vstddevf1mape DECIMAL(22,12);
            DECLARE vstddevf2mape DECIMAL(22,12);
            DECLARE vstddevf3mape DECIMAL(22,12);
            DECLARE vstddevf4mape DECIMAL(22,12);
            DECLARE vstddevf5mape DECIMAL(22,12);


            SET vstepserial = 4;                    
            SET vcreatestmt = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(week_of_year),  AVG(naivemape) avgnaive, SUM(original+naive2mape), AVG(f1mape) , AVG(f2mape), AVG(f3mape),AVG(f4mape), AVG(f5mape),
            STDDEV(f1mape), STDDEV(f2mape), STDDEV(f3mape),STDDEV(f4mape), STDDEV(f5mape) INTO 
            @vcountweek,
            @vavgnaive,
            @vtotal_sale,
            @vavgf1mape,
            @vavgf2mape,
            @vavgf3mape,
            @vavgf4mape,
            @vavgf5mape,
            @vstddevf1mape,
            @vstddevf2mape,
            @vstddevf3mape,
            @vstddevf4mape,
            @vstddevf5mape


            FROM ', vtable_name, ' WHERE stepserial IN (4)');


            SELECT vcreatestmt AS '**debug';

            SET @statement = vcreatestmt;

            PREPARE statement FROM @statement;

            EXECUTE statement;

            DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;

            INSERT INTO zdata2_thesis_summary VALUES
            (vtable_name, vweekday, vboarding_station_name,vdeboarding_station_name,
            vcountweek,
            vstepserial,
            vavgnaive,
            vtotal_sale,
            vavgf1mape,
            vavgf2mape,
            vavgf3mape,
            vavgf4mape,
            vavgf5mape,
            vstddevf1mape,
            vstddevf2mape,
            vstddevf3mape,
            vstddevf4mape,
            vstddevf5mape);             



            INSERT INTO zdata2_summary_log SELECT vtable_name, vcountweek;



        END BLOCK1STEP;


    END LOOP LOOP1;


    END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @vcountweek

is a **session variable** but you enter in  your second table zdata2_thesis_summary

> vcountweek

Which is empty, because you declared it and didn't fill it .

so make
 for all your session variables

```
SET vcountweek = @vcountweek;
```

before you insert or use the session variables directly

Comment: Thats a nice and succinct answer...explains the difference between session and local variables. I guess if I create a statement with concat and run it as I have done above, I have to use session variables as I found local variables are not working.

Comment: yes that's right. because variables don't "exist" in the executed sql statement. but why didn't you accept the answer?

Comment: I was not aware of the functionality. I have marked it as an answer now. Thanks for letting me know.